# why do i get fatal error because of Index out of range?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

```
var numbers = [45, 73, 195, 53]

//Write your code here
 //Replace this comment with your code.
var computedNumbers : [Double] = Array() 
for i in 0...numbers.count-1 {computedNumbers[i] = Double(numbers[i])*Double(numbers[i])}
print(computedNumbers)
```

When I try to run the code on swift code it gives me the following error: Fatal error: Index out of range. 
I'm trying to reproduce an array of double by multiplying every element in numbers array by itself.

Comment: Because computedNumbers[i doesnt have any values yet you are accessing it [i]. Insert values to array, using. Insert or add method

Comment: `for i in 0...numbers.count-1` is a *really* bad antipattern. Please read https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Proper%20Array%20Iteration.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your computedNumbers array is empty and you are trying to access computedNumbers[i] value in your for loop which is empty. if you want to add data in it, try this instead:

```
var numbers = [45, 73, 195, 53]

//Write your code here
 //Replace this comment with your code.
var computedNumbers : [Double] = []
for i in 0...numbers.count-1 {
  let num = Double(numbers[i])*Double(numbers[i])
  computedNumbers.append(num)
} 
print(computedNumbers)
```

Comment: this still crashes when `numbers` is empty, and is still really bad Swift code over all. It should just be `let numbers = [45, 73, 195, 53]` `let squares = numbers.map { $0 * $0 }`.

Comment: you are right. but as per the question, the number array is not empty.

Comment: That's not something you should rely on, particularly when "doing the right thing" is such an easy alternative.